# Select Count very slow using EF with Oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

I'm using EF 5 with Oracle database.

I'm doing a select count in a table with a specific parameter. When I'm using EF, the query returns the value 31, as expected, But the result takes about 10 seconds to be returned.

```
using (var serv = new Aperam.SIP.PXP.Negocio.Modelos.SIP_PA())
{
    var teste = (from ens in serv.PA_ENSAIOS_UM
                 where ens.COD_IDENT_UNMET == "FBLDY3840"
                 select ens).Count();
}
```

If I execute the simple query bellow the result is the same (31), but the result is showed in 500 milisecond.

```
SELECT 
       count(*)
  FROM 
       PA_ENSAIOS_UM
 WHERE 
       COD_IDENT_UNMET 'FBLDY3840'
```

There are a way to improve the performance when I'm using EF?

Note: There are 13.000.000 lines in this table.

Comment: Isn't the EF generated SQL query the same?

Comment: I was able to get the query only when I use ToList () instead of Count (). In this case the query is the same, but in EF the return takes more than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things you can try:

1. Capture the query that is being generated and see if it is the same as the one you are using.  Details can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469464), but essentially, you will instantiate your `DbContext` (let's call it "_context") and then set the `Database.Log` property to be the logging method.  It's fine if this method doesn't actually do anything--you can just set a breakpoint in there and see what's going on.

   So, as an example: define a logging function (I have a static class called "Logging" which uses nLog to write to files)

   ```
   public static void LogQuery(string queryData)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queryData))
           return;

       var message = string.Format("{0}{1}", 
           queryData.Trim().Contains(Environment.NewLine) ?
           Environment.NewLine : "", queryData);
       _sqlLogger.Info(message);
       _genLogger.Trace($"EntityFW query (len {message.Length} chars)");
   }
   ```

   Then when you create your context point to LogQuery:

   ```
   _context.Database.Log = Logging.LogQuery;
   ```
2. When you do your tests, remember that often the first run is the slowest because the server has to actually do the work, but on the subsequent runs, it often uses cached data.  Try running your tests 2-3 times back to back and see if they don't start to run in the same time.
3. I don't know if it generates the same query or not, but try this other form (which should be functionally equivalent, but may provide better time)

   ```
   var teste = serv.PA_ENSAIOS_UM.Count(ens=>ens.COD_IDENT_UNMET == "FBLDY3840");
   ```

I'm wondering if the version you have pulls data from the DB and THEN counts it.  If so, this other syntax may leave all the work to be done at the server, where it belongs.  Not sure, though, esp. since I haven't ever used EF with Oracle and I don't know if it behaves the same as SQL or not.